# AngularJS Feedback directive

Tags: angularjs, feedback

I'm trying to implement what looks to be a really cool [feedback directive](http://jacobscarter.github.io/angular-feedback/#/) but can't seem to even get the button to display...?

I went through the set up as described on the github page but no luck. This code was originally commented out:

```
`templateUrl: function(element, attributes) {
          return attributes.template || "angularsendfeedback.html";
        },`
```

so I just uncommented it... thinking I could just use that as the default HTML to get things going. The default `"angularsendfeedback.html"` is blank but it seemed like it already had default html in the js file.

Am I missing something or is the directive missing something? Is there another simple AngularJS directive for feedback out there... somewhere? Any recommendations?

Comment: put your code here or provide plunker for what you did?

Comment: @varit05 I actually found what seems to be a very similar directive but easier to implement,  angular-bootstrap-feedback